# Trying to set up GraphQL on Flask with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, graphql

I want to set up GraphQL to interact with my SQLAlchemy. I am using a Postgres DB (in which I created the tables/relationships already ((no data)) and I have connected to it just fine. I used automap_base since I created the db schema outside of Python.

When I import the database.py file into my app.py, the Class variables stay initialized to none, even after initializing the DB. This means my schema is sending type "None" rather than type "SQLAlchemyObjectType".

I come from the Javascript world and this seems like an async issue, and the call to the getters needs to be delayed a tad, but I am not sure.

````
```
from flask_graphql import GraphQLView
from database import init_db
from database import schema
...
init_db(app)

# Add the GraphQL endpoint
app.add_url_rule(
    "/graphql",
    view_func=GraphQLView.as_view(
    "graphql",
        schema=schema,
        graphiql=True,
    )
)
```
````

- Here is a pastebin to my app.py: https://pastebin.com/ajsMDdSE

  ```
  # SQLAlchemy
  db = SQLAlchemy()
  Base = automap_base()

  def init_db(app):
      global Base, db
      db.init_app(app)
      Base.prepare(db.engine, reflect=True)

  # Get models
  def get_user_model():
      return Base.classes.AppUser

  def get_link_model():
      return Base.classes.Link

  def get_link_stack_model():
      return Base.classes.LinkStack

  def get_password_model():
      return Base.classes.Password
  ```
- Here is a pastebin to my database.py: https://pastebin.com/NKTbFYrS
- Here is a pastebin to my SQL tables: https://pastebin.com/zwaN34ZC

And finally here is the error:

> File
> "/Users/vincenzomeschi/Documents/ListStack--V/server/database.py",
> line 35, in Meta
> model = get_user_model()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/vincenzomeschi/Documents/ListStack--V/server/database.py",
> line 18, in get_user_model
> return Base.classes.AppUser
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py",
> line 188, in **getattr**
> raise AttributeError(key) AttributeError: AppUser